# Do I really need the details of my previous passports to obtain Vietnamese EVisa?

Tags: passports, online-resources, vietnam, e-visas

I've been to Vietnam three times, but the last time was just before they introduced the E-Visa. Now I'm in Laos looking at the Vietnam E-Visa website and it has a question:
**Have you ever used any other passports to enter into Viet Nam?**.
[image: Part of the E-Visa form asking about other passports]

I of course don't travel with the details of my old passports. I'm hoping that this is just an ambiguously worded question about passports from other countries that people would have if they've immigrated or have dual citizenship etc, or maybe before a name change?

Can anyone confirm that I don't need to put in details from my old expired passports and can safely answer **No** to this question?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like the question Chinese consulates and Visa Centres ask, which is indeed about previous entries in the country on a previous passport. In the case you are hoping for, countries like Singapore or Malaysia ask about citizenship, rather than passport. I suspect they have decided the word 'passport' for a reason, and are asking about just that. Entries on a previous passport, whichever the citizenship. The screenshot you posted doesn't ask for citizenship, either...

Comment: If this sort of 'stuff' keeps up we may have to travel with details of our old passports. Like when they ask for where you've visited in the last n years- if I have a new passport I might not remember that one-day visit to wherever n-1 years ago.